# UnionFS-like filesystem for windows

Tags: windows-7, filesystems

I'm looking for something that works like UnionFS in Windows 7. My usecase: having clean code working directory in a read-only directory, and compiling it in a union filesystem which would store compiled binaries logically in the same place, but physically in different directory.

Libraries do not work this way, even though they were accepted as an answer in [UnionFS alike on windows, Virtually merge folders](https://superuser.com/questions/66857/unionfs-alike-on-windows-virtually-merge-folders) -- they only show top-level directories in one place.

The code itself is huge (2GB of data), and I'd like to avoid copying it for every build in my build server.

Answer (score 4):

There is a feature [Unified Write Filter (UWF) overlay](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/enterprise/uwfoverlay), but I don't know how to use it.

Comment: "UWF is a new feature for Standard 8, and is not available as part of Windows 8." Unlikely this is available in end-user Windows versions.

Comment: @DanielB  It [seems to be available for enterprise in Windows 10](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/mt571992.aspx) too.

Comment: Useful for other cases, but not this one.  Good to know and worth noting.

Answer (score 4):

It's possible nowadays but fairly complicated using rclone union mount with local directory "remotes".

rclone [union](https://rclone.org/union/) allows mergerfs style overlays including policies for where the new files get created etc.

rclone [mount](https://rclone.org/commands/rclone_mount/) allows you to mount any kind of rclone locally. It' based on [WinFSP](https://winfsp.dev/), which is the FUSE equivalent for Windows. Performance is not going to be amazing...

Answer (score 3):

You can make a poor-man's unionfs with symbolic links: reproduce the directory structure of the source, but make links (symbolic or hard) for the files. This should be suitable for your purpose as long as the build system doesn't try to modify source files.

With GNU cp, it's as easy as `cp -al` or `cp -as`. But I don't know if there is a port of GNU tools that understands Windows links.

If you need to call the mklink command, it can be done with POSIX tools (warning, typed directly into the browser):

```
cd SOURCE
find -type d -exec sh -c 'cd BUILDDIR && mkdir "$@"' _ {} +
find -type f -exec sh -c 'mklink "$1" "BUILDDIR/$1"' _ {} \;
```

I suppose there is a native Windows way involving Powershell, but I have no idea what it looks like. It might be worth investigating if your directory tree is large and your disks are fast because forking under Windows tends to be slow, and the commands above need to fork a lot.

Comment: The native way would be something like `for /R %BUILDDIR% %F in (*.*) do @junction X:%pnxF %F`, using the `junction` tool from sysinternals.

Comment: @MSalters Symbolic links are native to Windows now. And NTFS junctions are *not* the same thing.

Comment: @NickWhaley: Indeed, junctions are essentially hard links.

Answer (score 2):

Could you use symbolic links to fake this?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link  It's not answering the exact question but I think it will solve the use case you've given.

Comment: I don't see how could it... could you explain?

Comment: I don't know the way your build tree is structured but assuming it's something like src, src/bin, src/obj, then you can have bin and obj be symbolic links to wherever you want to the code to be. Just make sure your build isn't deleting those folders completely. Alternatively have src be the symbolic link to the "read only" then have the links in the read only go back. Either way you should be able to make it work.  Unless i'm completely missing your scenario.

Comment: I don't control the build procedure, and it can write everywhere.

Comment: @liori: for this use case, you could reproduce the directories and create symbolic links for every file (something like `cd SOURCE; find -type d -exec sh -c 'cd BUILDDIR && mkdir "$@"' _ {} +; find -type f -exec sh -c 'mklink "$1" "BUILDDIR/$1"' _ {} \;` or some Windows equivalent).

Comment: @Gilles: you make me think copying isn't that bad solution... (besides, could you make it into an answer?)

Answer (score 2):

I found this, but I don't really know how well it works:

- [winunionfs](http://code.google.com/p/winunionfs/)

Comment: Projects archived on Google Code are unmaintained.  You might want to look for an updated version somewhere.   Possibly a fork.

Answer (score 1):

While there is no OS support for union mounts in Windows yet, I think it's worth a try to implement a solution on the basis of VHD images. The idea is to:

1. Create one base VHD image with common files
2. Create a differential VHD linked to the base image
3. Mount the differential VHD
4. Directory junction from your original file system point to the directory on the differential VHD
5. Goto 2 for as many new projects with common files

I haven't tried this myself, but the only problem I see is that to use many differential images derived from the same base image in parallel you'd somehow need for them to all have different drive ids, otherwise windows disk manager might refuse to mount.

Comment: This sounds like what docker does when using the devicemapper storage driver, IIRC it used to be the default storage driver at some point. One feature was that it was fast. No idea what kind of performance would this solution get on Windows though.