# Is there such a thing as an 'overlay mount', 'unionfs' or something similar in Windows?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, filesystems

Is it possible on Windows NT to have one directory sort of on top of another?

For example I have a directory like this:

```
C:\foo
```

It has a file in it called `zoo.txt`

I have another directory like this:

```
C:\bar\baz
```

It has the file `museum.txt` in it.

I would like to be able to talk about `C:\foo\museum.txt` and automatically get `C:\bar\baz\museum.txt`.

Additionally, if a file named `C:\bar\baz\zoo.txt` is ever created, I would like that file when referencing `C:\foo\zoo.txt`

Lastly, if I create a file named `C:\foo\qux.txt` I would like that file to actually appear in `C:\bar\baz\qux.txt` and if I ever cancel the overlay mount or whatever mechanism I'm using to make this happen, it will disappear from `C:\foo\qux.txt`

Are these things possible?

Basically, I have a vendor supplied directory that needs to have some source code overlaid on top of it and compiled. But I would like the actual vendor supplied directory to remain in the state it was when it was shipped from the vendor.

Right now a backup is kept of this directory, and it is restored from backup before the source code is built, then the current version of the source code is copied onto it. This is very inefficient and error prone.

Comment: This seems to have been worded in such a way that people think I mean symbolic links, but that's not what I'm talking about.

Comment: possible duplicate of [UnionFS-like filesystem for windows](http://superuser.com/questions/185619/unionfs-like-filesystem-for-windows)

Comment: Can someone please close this as an exact duplicate for me?

Answer (score 0):

You are asking about [symbolic-links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_links)/[hard-links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_link)/[junction-points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_junction_point).

What you can do is to create one of the aforementioned links/points called `baz` in `C:\bar`, and have it point to `C:\foo` as the target. Now you can access and treat `C:\bar\baz` like an ordinary directory and whatever (for the most part) you do to it will actually occur in `C:\foo`.

Comment: It seems to me that the poster is looking for overlayfs/unionfs kind of mounts, not just simple links.

Comment: @grawity: That's what I was thinking too. :-) But it's nice to know that junction points exist. They could be useful for other things.