# Make the contents of two folders appear in one

Tags: windows-7, symbolic-link

In Windows 7, I have three folders: 
"Images", 
"assets" 
and "all".

I want the *contents* of "Images " and "assets" to appear in "all" automatically without copying those files into that folder (e.g. I don't want to duplicate the files). I also only want the contents to be copied over and not the folders themslves (The reason for this is that if the folders are copied over, they will become sub-directories. I am using a printing hot folder that access "all" but it can't see any subdirectories in "all").

When Images and Assets are updated (e.g. with files being added or deleted), "all" should automatically update as well.

How can I do this?

This is what I have tried:

[Libraries](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/windows7/products/features/libraries): This is a feature built into Windows. It works exactly as I want. However, the print hot folder cannot recognise the library as a folder.

[Sym Link Extension](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/): I can use this to make the "images" and "assets" folders appear as a sub directories of "all". However, I want the contents of "images"/"assets" to appear in the "all" folder (I don't want the directories to appear as sub directories, because as stated, the print hot folder cannot access sub directories).

Comment: Can your "printing hot folder" access two or more folders? Then just point it to access both _images_ and _assets_. Granted, this isn't what you want, but I don't think you can easily auto-symlink merge two folders into one without running into problems. How will you manage conflicts?

Comment: No it can only access one folder.

Comment: You are basically asking for https://superuser.com/questions/185619/unionfs-like-filesystem-for-windows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can't be easily done with the tools available in Windows.

Libraries are not regular folders but are *virtual* folders. Not many applications can use Windows Shell objects directly which are not file system objects.

So a script which creates *hard links* in "all" for all the files in "Assets" and "Images" seems to be the easiest way.

```
cd all
rem Remove all the files in all
del /f /q *.*

rem Create hard links to files from assets and images
for %I in (<full-path-to>\assets\*.*) do mklink /h "%~nxI" "%I"
for %I in (<full-path-to>\images\*.*) do mklink /h "%~nxI" "%I"
```

Here `%~nxI` will expand to file name and extension only, without the path. If the folders are on different drives, you have to use symbolic links: remove `/h` switch from `mklink` command.

Run the script above every time the contents of "Assets" and/or "Images" is updated, or run it periodically.

A better solution would watch for file updates in "Assets" and "Images" and synchronize the changes to "all".

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know for sure is to make a script that creates hard links in "All" to every file from "Assets" and "Images".

But I think that this method is quite an overkill for such a simple task.

Answer (score -1):

The only best way is to use symbolic-links(symlink) method . With this [`symlink-creator.bat`](https://puvox.software/blog/easiest-method-create-symlink-symbolic/) file, just drag all (files & folders) from desired folder and enter destination path.