# linux overlayfs shared to windows - any issues?

Tags: linux, windows, virtual-machine

I have a situation similar to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/185619/unionfs-like-filesystem-for-windows).

Someone gave me this idea: create a Linux VM and create overlayfs filesystems then share those to the Windows guest OS.

Besides the standard issue of "it'll be slow because of VM interface", are there any issues with sharing Linux overlayfs partitions to Windows?

Comment: What Virtual software are using on the host machine?

Comment: @Alex I'm open to any suggestions. I moved this question cause a mod was angry that it didn't belong in stackoverflow.

Comment: Then I will answer in "answer", because if you would need additional info I can edit or add additional information there

Comment: Never done this on Windows, sorry, misread your requirements, so let delete then my answer because I see now it irrelevant